# Neo4j Traversal API limitation?

Tags: java, neo4j, graph-traversal

we are trying to use the Traversal API to retrieve, for a given set of company nodes, only the company nodes that provide all the products that are contained in the product Nodes list. Prior attempts at using Cypher were not performing well. In this example:

```
Company 1 provides product A and B
Company 2 provides product A and B and C
Company 3 provides product A and C
```

If all 3 companies are included in company list query, and product A and C are in product list in query, we would want returned only Company 2 and 3 since they provide product A and C. Here is our query:

```java
for ( Path position : Traversal.description()
.depthFirst()
.uniqueness(Uniqueness.NODE_GLOBAL)
.relationships(Rels.PROVIDES_PRODUCT, Direction.OUTGOING)
.evaluator((Evaluator) Evaluators.includeWhereEndNodeIs(productNodes))
.traverse(companyNodes))
```

If we use the `Evaluator.includeWhereEndNodeIs(productNodes)` we get back all the companies that provide ANY of the products in the `productNodes` list(all 3 companies in above example). If we use the `Evaluators.includeIfContainsAll(productNodes)` evaluator, we don't get any company nodes back if there is more than one product in the product nodes list.

Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: can you add the original cypher query? That would make it much easier to understand waht you want to achieve.

Comment: Michael - here is the original Cypher query we had - we only want companies returned that provide all products in the list and this syntax did not work: START company=node(10719,37496,37417,37464), product=node(37512,65094) WHERE company-->product RETURN company, product;     Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's possible in one statement, but you could nest them. Company2 and Company3 will be returned in the following case:

```
for (final Path position : Traversal
            .description()
            .depthFirst()
            .uniqueness(Uniqueness.RELATIONSHIP_LEVEL)
            .relationships(RelType.PROVIDES_PRODUCT, Direction.OUTGOING)
            .evaluator(
                    (Evaluator) Evaluators.endNodeIs(Evaluation.INCLUDE_AND_CONTINUE, Evaluation.EXCLUDE_AND_CONTINUE,
                            productA)).traverse(company1, company2, company3)) {
        for (final Path position2 : Traversal
                .description()
                .depthFirst()
                .uniqueness(Uniqueness.RELATIONSHIP_LEVEL)
                .relationships(RelType.PROVIDES_PRODUCT, Direction.OUTGOING)
                .evaluator(
                        (Evaluator) Evaluators.endNodeIs(Evaluation.INCLUDE_AND_CONTINUE, Evaluation.EXCLUDE_AND_CONTINUE,
                                productC)).traverse(position.startNode())) {
            System.out.println(position2.startNode());
        }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Trying this out - no luck yet though as the syntax is a bit difficult.

Answer (score 0):

Are the (company)-[:PROVIDES_PRODUCT]->(product) only one level always? In that case it would be fine with a simple loop like this:

```
Set<Node> companies = new HashSet<Node>( asList( companyNodes ) );
for ( Node product : productNodes )
{
    Set<Node> companiesForThisProduct = new HashSet<Node>();
    for ( Relationship rel : product.getRelationships( PROVIDES_PRODUCT, INCOMING ) )
        companiesForThisProduct.add( rel.getStartNode() );
    companies.retainAll( companiesForThisProduct );
}
```

I quickly hacked up your example with your dataset and it works fine.